# Insert record through email on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email

I have developed a messaging system on rails3.As per the requirements, when User A commented any message to UserB then the message will be stored on the DB, also email notification will be sent.

Now my requirement is When User B replying the email notification though mail with some messages, it should get inserted on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather complex task compared to sending emails. Essentially, you'll have a few steps:

- Set up a receive method in your mailer
- Set up your email server to forward emails to your app
- Handle processing the email content
- Save into the database

Probably the most straight-forward explination of the entire process can be found in this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#receiving-emails).